# How do I print dictionary length in tkinter output widget, not just in cmd

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have successfull created a translator app that translate English words to my native language. I created a button that prints out the length of the dictionary in tkinter GUI, but the button only prints the result in CMD; how do I make it print out the result in the the output widget I created? Bellow is an excerpt of the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter. messagebox
root=Tk()
root.geometry('250x200')
root.title("Meta' Translator")
root.configure(background="#35424a")

def clk():
    print(len(exlist))

#heading
lab=Label(root,text='Translate English Words to Meta\'',font=('none 11 bold'))
lab.place(x=0,y=2)

#output label
lab=Text(root,width=5,height=1,font=('Times 18'),fg="black")
lab.place(x=59,y=70)

#print button
but=Button(root,padx=3,pady=3,text='Length',command=clk,bg='powder blue',font=('none 10 bold'))
but.place(x=0,y=70)


exlist={
    "abdomen":"fɨbûm", "abdomens":"tɨbûm",
    "adam's apple":"ɨ̀fɨ̀g ədɔ'", "adam's apples":"tɨ̀fɨ̀g ədɔ'",
    "ankle":"ɨgúm ǝwù"
    }

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First of all why are you using the same variable name for the label and the text widgets? Second of all, when you say "the output widget I created" do you mean the label or text widget. Both of them can be used as output.

Comment: Sorry, it was an error; the commend "#output label" was meant to be #output widget. I was supposed to title the variable beneath lab2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#THANKS JONAS FOR HELPING OUT!
from tkinter import *
import tkinter. messagebox
root=Tk()
root.geometry('250x200')
root.title("Meta' Translator")
root.configure(background="#35424a")

#Courtesy of Jonas
def clk():
    lab2.delete(1.0,"end") #delete the current content if there is some
    lab2.insert(1.0, str(len(exlist)))

#heading
lab=Label(root,text='Translate English Words to Meta\'',font=('none 11 bold'))
lab.place(x=0,y=2)

#output widget
lab2=Text(root,width=5,height=1,font=('Times 18'),fg="black")
lab2.place(x=59,y=70)

#print button
but=Button(root,padx=3,pady=3,text='Length',command=clk,bg='powder blue',font= 
('none 10 bold'))
but.place(x=0,y=70)


exlist={
    "abdomen":"fɨbûm", "abdomens":"tɨbûm",
    "adam's apple":"ɨ̀fɨ̀g ədɔ'", "adam's apples":"tɨ̀fɨ̀g ədɔ'",
    "ankle":"ɨgúm ǝwù"
    }

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If this code is from another answer, then delete this and mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: The new code is the correction I made from the solution Jonas provided.

Comment: If Jonas solution gave you the answer, then accept it and delete this.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the text of your `Text()`-object inside you `clk()`-function with the `insert()` method:

```
def clk():
    lab.delete(1.0,"end") #delete the current content if there is some
    lab.insert(1.0, str(len(exlist)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just solved my problem. It worked!

Comment: btw it is convention that you put the `1.0` in quote marks. Also you don't need to call `str` - `<tkinter.Text>.insert` can take all built-in types. Also also it it convention to insert the text at the `"end"` when there is nothing in the widget.

Comment: @TheLizzard Convention? It is strictly recommended to use `float` instead of `str` as index, as float and str have different meaning when rounded off.

Comment: @CoolCloud Floats get rounded so `text.insert(1.1, "a")` becomes the same as `text.insert(1.10, "a")`. That is why it is strongly recommended that you use strings instead of floats

Comment: @CoolCloud also floats tend to do this: `0.30000000000000004` because of limitations with floats. That is why strings are better for indexes

Comment: @TheLizzard Using '1.10' instead of 1.10 is also a mistake. And I don't see why python would change 1.1 into 1.10 or vice-versa.

Comment: @CoolCloud in maths 1.10 is the same as 1.1. That is why in python if you do `a = 1.10` then do `print(a)` you will get 1.1 When using tkinter indexes `"1.10"` isn't the same as `"1.1"`. That is why you use strings.

Comment: @TheLizzard I realize that, but I thought `Text` indexes were interpreted as `float`, oops.

Comment: @CoolCloud :D Text widgets use strings.